# Multiple usage of generator from list in Python

Tags: python, list, generator

Basically, I'm in following situation - I generate a list, e.g.

```
l = [2*x for x in range(10)]
```

which I iterate through later on multipletimes, e.g.

```
for i in l: print i    # 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
for i in l: print i    # 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
for i in l: print i    # 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
```

The problem is that the list is way too large to fit into memory, hence I use its generator form, i.e.:

```
l = (2*x for x in range(10))
```

However, after this construction only first iteration works:

```
for i in l: print i    # 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
for i in l: print i    #
for i in l: print i    #
```

Where is the problem? How may I iterate through it multipletimes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your generator is exhausted the first time. You should recreate your generator each time to *renew* it:

```
l = (2*x for x in range(10))
for i in l: print i
l = (2*x for x in range(10))
for i in l: print i
```

(Note: you should use `xrange` in python 2 because `range` creates a list in memory)

You can create also a shortcut function to help you or even a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator):

```
def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield 2 * i
```

and then:

```
 for i in gen(): print i
 for i in gen(): print i
```

Comment: Should probably note that `xrange` is the generator version of `range` in python 2, whereas `range` in python 3+ is a generator and there is no `xrange`.

Comment: @MylesGallagher yes I updated. I guessed we were talking only for python 2.

Comment: I like the generator function. Alternatively, for such a simple generator, a lambda would be acceptable, eg `gen = lambda : (2*x for x in xrange(10))`. And of course either of these functions could be given multiplier and length args to make them more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

You can also iterate on the generator directly:

```
for i in (2*x for x in range(10)): print i
for i in (2*x for x in range(10)): print i
...
```

Comment: True, but that's not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).